# how to view and edit indexeddb database

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, indexeddb

how can I open sqlite database resides locally on my drive using indexeddb. or is there a way or tool  to open and edit indexeddb when I create it using javascript code because I need to copy more than 10000 records in it from mdb database. please help me in this issue. thanks in advance

Comment: May I ask what gives you the idea that IndexedDB is a SqliteDB? (Because it isn't: [Chrome uses LevelDB as its backing store](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a77a9a172b05957ad025104fc62979d5e2b87323/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/indexeddb/docs/idb_data_path.md), IIRC it's only Safari that uses Sqlite)

Comment: Please post what you have tried or how can reproduce the error

Comment: thank you Dai for your answer, but I cannot edit it in chrome browser.